# Express routing and URL parsing when using separate modules

Tags: node.js, express, module, routes

I'd like to be able to parse a url query for data and use it in my response. In my app file I have the following:

```
var entry = require('./routes/entry');
app.use('/entry*', entry);
```

in my route file:

```
router.get('/:name', function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.params.name);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Currently I am getting a 404 error.

I'm wondering how I can get a name parameter out of the url. So if someone were to type .../entry/example then the response would be "example."

A lot of my confusion stems from what should be handled by the router and what the app.use should have as its URL parameter. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the asterisk * from /entry and it should start working as expected.  I created a local express application and inserting the asterisk causes the same issue.